# How To Change The Directory For Vite Manifest

Tags: vue.js, vite, manifest.json

I would like vite manifest to be available in the public_html/build/ directory for my website but I keep getting the error Vite manifest not found at: public_html/public/build/manifest.json. This is my config how would I modify that to make it at the build/ instead of public/build?

```
//vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    },
   
  },
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          base: null,
          includeAbsolute: false,
        },
      },
    }),
    VueI18nPlugin({
        include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), 'resources/js/locales/**'),
      }),
  ],
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
      publicDir: 'build',
      manifest: true, 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not make my manfiest avaliable in public_html/build but I can leave all my compiled files there and move it to public/build and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a bash file that ran the npm command then moved the file to the public directory as needed.
I run one command and it does everything I need easily with no extra work...

```
Filename: npm_run_build.bash
Contents: 
#!/bin/bash
npm run build
mv ./public_html/build/manifest.json ./public/build/manifest.json
```

Then I just run the command

```
"bash npm_run_build.bash"
```

in place of hte command

```
npm run build
```

It does the build then moves the file to the place needed so I can run the script without any extra work...